# What does it mean when square brackets appear around a class name in the VS 2008 IDE?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, watch-window

In my watch window in VS2008, I'm looking at an `IEnumerable<classX>`. Expanding the `IEnumerable`, some elements are shown with a Value of `{classX}`. Others appear with a Value of `{[classX]}`. What's the difference? Why are there square brackets on some of them?

Answer (score 0):

The class inside the curly brackets represents the dynamic type of the object you are referring to. e.g. Below code should explain this...

```
class Parent1
{
 int p1;
};

class Child1:Parent1
{
 int c1;
}

class Child2:Parent1
{
 int c2;
}

void main()
{
 Parent1 objP1 = new Child1();
}
```

Now if you see objP1 in debugger windows, you would see [Child1] which is the dynamic type for objP1. Expanding this further, you can see contents that belong to Child1.

Comment: @[Palak.Maheria](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2432065/palak-maheria), didn't understand why you changed from [square] brackets to {curly} brackets?

Comment: Neither do I understand